Optimizing over convex polynomials
I have the following optimization problem involving symbolic polynomials:
I want to define two polynomials A(x) and B(x) (of fixed degree, say d), and let P(x) be a polynomial such that P''(x) = A(x)^2 + B(x)^2. We also require P(0) = P'(0) = 0 so that P is uniquely determined by A and B.
I want to optimize the coefficients of A and B to minimize a function f(P), where (for instance)
f(P) = (coefficient of x^3 in P)^2 - | (coefficient of x^2 in P) - 1 |.
Here I used a specific f for the example, but I am interesting in something more general (which may involve the coefficients of P, or P(a) for some fixed a, etc.).
So I tried using sympy to define A and B, but then if I try using cvxpy to minimize, it's not compatible.
So what package(s) should I use in Python ?
Thank you !

scipy has a few functions for these kinds of problems

It is really too abstract a question for here and not yet quite well defined enough. It would be better off asked in the Maths section with a bit more detail. Your options are probably some sort of barrier function or some very cunning algebra if the exact form of the convex polynomials permit it.

@MartinBrown You're right. I have just modified my message a lot to make it much simpler, and depending on what I find for this specific simple example, I'll try and generalize it.
